# Default Leaflet icon is not showing

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I want to use default icon provided by leaflet instead of using something else. But unfortunately i am not seeing anything, not even error.

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'my-icon.png',
            iconSize: [38, 95],
            iconAnchor: [22, 94],
            popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
            shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
            shadowSize: [68, 95],
            shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
        });
        L.marker([50,10], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: look at this example https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/!your images are in that folder?

Comment: Question talks about default icon, code shows custom icon. Which one you want to show then?

Comment: Is your my-icon.png file in the same folder where your js file is?

Answer (score 1):

In order to meet my requirement i used icon url that i received in my network tab of console in chrome. This works fine as well:

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'data:image/png;base64,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'
})

L.marker([50,10], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(this.map);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default icon is defined as `L.Icon.Default`. To use it do not pass icon to the marker. So the code should be

`L.marker([50,10]).addTo(map);`

Comment: i tried this, but its not priniting any icon. Instead its showing error of png image not found

Comment: turns out, for the default icon. icon proper should be omitted. I have edited the answer

Comment: Unfortunately , your updated answer also don't work, i have tried this already.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the current path of the icon in leaflet css. So don't use the url leaflet.css, download the file and change it.

```
.leaflet-default-icon-path {
    background-image: url(https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png);
}
```